# broadcast receiver doesn't respond to broadcast message

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have set a broadcast receiver, but it doesn't get the broadcast message i send it:

my manifest

```
<receiver android:name="BootReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService.LOCATION_BROAD_MSG" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

sending (debug shows I reach the send line)

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
public static final String LOCATION_BROAD_MSG = "Hello";
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

public LocationManager locationManager;
public MyLocationListener listener;
public Location previousBestLocation = null;

Intent intent;
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(LOCATION_BROAD_MSG);      
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      

}

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
       intent = new Intent(LOCATION_BROAD_MSG); 
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());     
                intent.putExtra("Provider", loc.getProvider());                 
                sendBroadcast(intent);          

            }                               
        }

}
```

receiving (onReceive never reached during debug)

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (intent != null)
        {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action != null)
            {
                if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
                {
                                            //   Log.d("receiver","action is: boot");
                }

                if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationService.LOCATION_BROAD_MSG))
                {
                        //Toast.makeText(, "wee hee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

            }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, did you tried to put a log in the root of your onReceive method? I can see that you have one but is in the if statements.. and also could you tell us what values have your android package from the manifest file and LOCATION_BROAD_MSG constant? It might be that the BootReceive from manifest doesn't know where is the actual class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
public static final String LOCATION_BROAD_MSG = "com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService.LOCATION_BROAD_MSG";
```

You have registered `com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService.LOCATION_BROAD_MSG`as a intent filter in receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are registering the broadcast to receive messages from:
`com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService.LOCATION_BROAD_MSG` and you are sending this:
`LOCATION_BROAD_MSG = "Hello"` ..

you should have

```
public static final String LOCATION_BROAD_MSG = "com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService.LOCATION_BROAD_MSG";
```